# string.punctuation deleting a value

Tags: python, string, counter

So I'm writing a code that counts the amount of words that are #ed and if a word isn't #ed, it ignores it.

When I run the code:

```
import string
all = []
count = {}
word = []
line = input("Tweet: ").lower().strip(string.punctuation)
while line != '':
  word.extend(line.split())
  line = input("Tweet: ").lower().strip(string.punctuation)
for w in word:
  if w.startswith('#'):
    count[w] = count.get(w, 0) + 1
for word in sorted(count):
  print(word, count[word])
```

and I input #Python is #AWESOME!

it outputs #awesome 1 but no #python 1

I need it to output all #ed words and count how many are used. I think the problem is caused by the string.punctuation.

Comment: `strip` removes the characters in its argument from the beginning and end of the string, so `strip(string.punctuation)` will remove the `#` at the beginning of `#Python is #AWESOME!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably will work for you

```
import string
all = []
count = {}
word = []
line = input("Tweet: ").lower().rstrip(string.punctuation)
while line != '.':
  word.extend(line.split())
  line = input("Tweet: ").lower().rstrip(string.punctuation)
for w in word:
  if w.startswith('#'):
    count[w] = count.get(w, 0) + 1
for word in sorted(count):
  print(word, count[word])
```

or

```
import string
all = []
count = {}
word = []
line = input("Tweet: ").lower()
while line != '.':
  word.extend(line.split())
  line = input("Tweet: ").lower()
for w in word:
  if w.startswith('#'):
    w = w.rstrip(string.punctuation)
    count[w] = count.get(w, 0) + 1
for word in sorted(count):
  print(word, count[word])
```

Comment: the second one was correct, i wanted to keep the #s at the front of the printed values. I probably should've specified that

Answer (score 0):

You are partly correct!

```
.strip(string.punctuation)
```

is the culprit.

According to [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation), # is part of the string.punctuation-set.

Also from [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), on the `strip`-function:

> string.strip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters
>   removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are
>   removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters
>   in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this
>   method is called on.

Thus, you are removing the leading (e.g. first) # and the string which is saved in your variable `line` is `"python is #awesome"`.
Your while-loop will also never exit, as `".".strip(string.punctuation) == ""`.
It seems you really do not want the `.strip`-methods there at all. If it was meant to remove the last character only if it is punctuation, use `"your string".rstrip(string.punctuation)` instead